# Should hierarchy be included within css names?

Tags: html, css, naming

What is the 'best practice' in terms of including hierarchy within css names? EG:, suppose we have the following html:

```
<div class="foo">
<div class="$className2">
<div class="$className3">123
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Should $className2 include 'foo-' as a prefix, and $className3 include both 'foo-' and $className2 as a prefix? Or should the parent class names not be included within child class names?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to include a parent class's name. CSS selectors will handle any parent formatting you need.

A class, should be describing the type of content you are using. For example

```
<div class="sidebar">
<div class="error">
</div>
</div>
```

It is likely that you are going to want to have formatting specific to the error class, that is irrespective of the sidebar class. In the event that you want formatting for the error class that is specific to the sidebar, a css selector could handle that for you

```
.sidebar > .error
```

or

```
.sidebar .error
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simply, are you reusing those class names or will you be reusing those class names anywhere other than in the same kind of structure?  If not then it is not necessary to limit it by parent.  If you are, however, then it would be a good idea to explicitly indicate which child element is which by including their parent node selectors.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't hard best practices when it comes to CSS class naming.  Relevant factors like how many rules you have, how modular your components are, and the scale of your website are important considerations.

For small sites, I prefer to keep the CSS classes very simple.

In your CSS, you can use a nested selector to target elements that are structured in the way you presented like this:

```
.foo > .bar > .baz { ... }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="baz">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For larger sites, or if you're looking for a prescriptive naming pattern, one popular methodology is [block-element modifier (BEM)](http://getbem.com/naming/).

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I do most of the time is to prepend an underscore to child classes - I would use the following css for the html from your example:

```
.foo { ... }
.foo ._$className2 { .. }
.foo ._$className3 { .. }
```

In this case, ".foo" would be wrapping something like a "foo component". And every child class that is only used inside this wrapper (meaning it wouldn't make sense on its own) is prepended with an underscore. This keeps your css clean and makes it easy for you to see whether a class is intended to be applied to elements everywhere on the page or whether it should appear in a special context.